# functions for crud operations without specifying database name

Tags: php, mongodb, crud

I have connected my php web app to mongodb with the help of simplemongophp library. Now what I want is ..the operations like read or update should perform without specifying the database name explicitly and all the crud operations should be in the form of functions.
here is a piece of code i have tried

```
include ('Db.php');
include ('Dbo.php');
   // i dont want to specify the db name explicitly 
Db::addConnection(new Mongo(),'two');
function non(){
echo "$this->name is . \n";
}
Dbo::addClass('php','gfyhfh');
Db::batchInsert('gfyhfh',array(
array('name'=>'bjhghgjh','hobbies'=>'distin')));
static function insertion()
{
Db::batchInsert('gfyhfh',array(
array('flower'=>'rose')));
}
?>
```

This is showing error .so can anyone tell me how do i do it.Thankyou

Comment: Unless there is a much newer fork of [simplemongophp](https://github.com/ibwhite/simplemongophp), it looks like this hasn't been updated since September 2010. In release terms, this is circa MongoDB 1.6. There have been *massive* improvements in features and functionality in the in the last 3 1/2 years, and I would strongly encourage you to start with the latest MongoDB 2.4.x server, the [officially supported MongoDB PHP driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php), and work through the [PHP tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) to learn the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't tell MongoDB what database it needs then how does it know what database to write to? This goes for SQL techs as well.

There is currently no way of connecting to MongoDB without specifying a database name.

Comment: can you tell me how to write crud operations in functions for the above code